# Bottom Table "footer" working on only 2/3 pages HTML

Tags: html

so I am trying to get basically just name, date, number down the bottom in its own row of the table although it works on two of the pages I cannot get it working on the homepage even if I copy/paste from the working ones. Was wondering if anyone out there could take a look and let me know whats wrong (knowing my luck its probably something small)

Here is the one not working;

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>
 <table border = "1">
  <tr valign = "top">
   <th colspan = "4"><img src="C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ICAWEB301A_AssessFiles\Images\Banner.PNG" width="1200" height="200"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th><a href="C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ICAWEB301A_AssessFiles\homepage.html">Home</a></th>
   <td rowspan = "3"><img src="C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ICAWEB301A_AssessFiles\Images\MainPic.PNG" height = "250"></td>
   <td rowspan = "3" width = "500">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        In id mi vitae velit tempus ultrices. Proin varius, nibh 
        dictum facilisis gravida, lacus nunc scelerisque nulla, 
        eget mollis nunc risus eu odio. Donec quis dolor interdum 
        odio molestie viverra. Duis dui ante, molestie in rhoncus 
        eget, tempor ac diam. Donec erat dui, imperdiet ac varius 
        eget, accumsan vel mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec 
        condimentum congue tempus.<p> 
        Fusce aliquet vehicula euismod. Cras eleifend euismod nisl 
        eu congue. Donec placerat, felis ut feugiat tempor, arcu 
        lacus sollicitudin urna, vel ultricies mi dolor sit amet 
        quam. Ut sed justo nulla, id porttitor purus. Maecenas dolor 
        libero, laoreet pharetra tincidunt vitae, congue ornare erat.
        Cras vitae interdum quam. Donec accumsan lectus mattis 
        neque adipiscing fringilla. Sed aliquam mi non metus 
        elementum ac elementum lectus pellentesque. Nullam risus
        diam, gravida ac ullamcorper vel, placerat vitae lorem. 
        Cras in libero sit amet metus rhoncus semper iaculis nec 
        dui. Integer adipiscing auctor lectus vel hendrerit. </td>
   <td rowspan = "3"><img src="C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ICAWEB301A_AssessFiles\Images\latestNews.PNG"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th><a href="C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ICAWEB301A_AssessFiles\services.html">Services</a></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th width = "200"><a href="C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ICAWEB301A_AssessFiles\contact.html">Contact</a></th>
  </tr>
  <tr valign = "bottom">
   <td colspan = "4">Name: - ....... Number: - ....... Date: Janurary 27, 2015</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 
 
 
</body>


</html>
```

and here is the working one;

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Services</title>
</head>

<body>
 <table border = "1">
  <tr valign = "top">
   <th colspan = "4"><img src="C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ICAWEB301A_AssessFiles\Images\Banner.PNG" width="1200" height="200"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th><a href="C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ICAWEB301A_AssessFiles\homepage.html">Home</a></th>
   <td rowspan = "3" width = "100"></td>
   <td rowspan = "3" width = "700"><strong>SERVICES</strong><br>
    <ul>
     <li>class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora</li>
     <li>torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos</li>
     <li>himenaeos. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
     <li>consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam</li>
     <li>dui quis auctor pharetra, odio risus </li>
     <li>sodales mauris, non scelerisque ligula </li>
     <li>justo eu ligula. Mauris metus neque</li>
     <li>dictum cursus fermentum sit amet</li>
     <li>lobortis nec sem. Fusce ante mauris</li>
     <li>consequat id feugiat nec, venenatis </li>
     <li>Quisque posuere accumsan orci, a faucibus</li>
    </ul> </td>
    <td rowspan = "3" colspan = "2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th><a href="C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ICAWEB301A_AssessFiles\services.html">Services</a></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th width = "150"><a href="C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\ICAWEB301A_AssessFiles\contact.html">Contact</a></th>
  </tr>
  <tr valign = "bottom">
   <th colspan = "4">Name: - ....... Number: - ....... Date: Janurary 27, 2015</th>
  </tr> 
  
 </table>
 
 
 
</body>


</html>
```

Thanks a lot for the help :/ I just can't seem to understand why two work but the other one does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<center>
<tr valign = "bottom">
            <th colspan = "4">Name: - ....... Number: - ....... Date: Janurary 27, 2015</th>
        </tr>
```

It worked when I used th. Try putting this...

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tr valign = "bottom">
            <th colspan = "4">Name: - ....... Number: - ....... Date: Janurary 27, 2015</th>
        </tr>
```

Put this code as replacement to your footer code that is not working.
You used TD tag instead of TH.

Comment: I forgot to mention sorry, I have tried with th and it still will not work on that one page. Thanks though